# Python class variable dependencies

Tags: python

If have a class that looks something like

```
import numpy as np

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.x = args[0]
        self.y = args[1]
        self.values = np.array([self.x, self.y])
```

And I want to be able to update both `x` and `values[0]` with a single call

```
a = Test((1., 2.))
a.x = 2.
```

so that `a.x = 2.` and `a.values[0] = 2.` I am sort of new when it comes to OOP, so please excuse me if this is obvious.

Comment: Look at Python [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).  But it's not clear why you need to do this.  You can just have `values` and then do `self.values[0]` to get what you're calling `x`.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks. This looks like it might be useful for me. x and y are really just meant to be a simple and intuitive interface for the user. While the values array is actually what I want to work with. I think the properties option is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write a function to do this:

```
def SetX(value):
  self.x = value
  self.values[0] = value
```

Comment: And then the usage would be something like a.SetX(2.)?

Comment: That seems a bit ugly. Is that my fault for having the 'redundant' variable?

Comment: @inJeans Yes. If you want the values in a numpy array, they should just be there, there's no real need to have x and y

Comment: Okay. Thanks. The x and y were supposed to be for user convenience, while the bumpy array was to be for speed and efficiency. Maybe I'll rethink my implementation. Thanks again.

Comment: Using a property makes this simpler.